# Facebook events request with dynamically captured access_token returns empty data

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-events

why does the following javascript return empty data?

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                      if (response.status === 'connected') {
                          var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                            console.log("accessToken:", accessToken);
                          //mainCall(accessToken);

            FB.api('/me/events/',
                  'GET',
                    {
                        "pretty":"1",
                        "limit":100,
                        "access_token": accessToken
                    },
                      function(response) {
                      newVue(response); // small vue.js template 
                      console.log(response);
                        });
                    } 
            } );
```

if I separately get the access token, hardcode it then call FB.api I get an array of 100 results as expected.

Comment: There is no need to specify the access token yourself (unless you wanted to use a different one than a user access token for the current app user), the SDK handles that on its own.

Comment: Sending access_token with the request returns OAuthException error with message "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

I know I need the access_token. as I said above if I hardcode it into the req I have no problem. it's only when I try to capture it then pass it to FB.api's params that I get empty array

Comment: There should be no need to explicitly pass that parameter in the first place. Can you show how you are initializing the SDK?

Comment: `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

              FB.init({
                appId      : '###############',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.10'
                });


             FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
`

Comment: Add `status: true`, and see what happens then.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @CBroe, your suggestion made no difference.
however I was able to fix by doing `FB.api('/me/events/?access_token=' + FB.getAccessToken(),`

Comment: this question can be closed